# Desktop screen capture with compiz running 

Tags: linux, screen-capture, compiz

When running Compiz (Linux), let say I'm on Desktop #1 and I have an application running on Desktop #3.  Is it possible to take a screenshot of the window (not the entire desktop) running on #3 from #1 ?

Well, I don't really expect anyone to answer this cause I've searched the entire net but I would feel guilty for not giving it a try.

Answer (score 1):

[Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/2009/03/shutter-070-released/) can do this.  As shown below, just select from the dropdown list the window you want. The list contains all apps currently running.

[image: Shutter]

Answer (score 1):

I use [Ksnapshot](http://freshmeat.net/projects/ksnapshot/) on my Multi monitor setup.  Allows for "window under cursor" and "region" amongst others.

Comment: Ksnapshot - you mean

Answer (score 0):

Why is compiz pertinent to this question?

If it's because you're having rendering issues (with opengl/video overlays) and you're using Intel graphics, grab the latest driver and switch your graphics mode to UXA in xorg.conf .. that might help.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the id of the window, you can use

```
import -window <id>
```

To get the id of the window, you can use `xprop`.

However, although running with a composite manager should help in your case, it may still be possible that the data you obtain will simply be corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) you can [use import](http://tips.webdesign10.com/how-to-take-a-screenshot-on-ubuntu-linux)

```
import -window root MyScreenshot.png
```

Use another ID for the other window.